# Redefining "for" operator

Tags: python, cpython

Is there any way to redefine `for`, or define a new operator with same syntax as `for` that doesn't require recompiling CPython?

IE, something like this

```
gfor i in range(10):
  i+=1
```

Comment: Can I ask _why_ you would want to do this?  Nobody who reads your code would know what `gfor` even means :-)...

Comment: The idea is that I have an engine that can run `for` loops on GPU, and I'm trying to make the most Python-friendly wrapper for it

Comment: Yeah, that's probably not going to work -- At least not simply.  You could do something like what `Cython` has done (`cdef` rather than `def`).  Of course, then you need to write your own parser which converts the python-like code into C code into a compiled shared object library that can be imported at runtime...

Comment: I'd suggest looking at http://numba.pydata.org/, and the associated https://github.com/numba/numba -- compiling Python to run on the GPU has already been done.

Comment: (...but in general, being able to redefine behavior of your basic loops from native code in a language is generally the kind of thing you can only get away with in LISPs -- where such constructs are typically just standard-library macros out-of-the-box).

Comment: thanks, it seems for Numba they use a function decorator that captures function object and then decompiles it with https://github.com/numba/meta

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  `for` is a keyword, not an operator.  As such, it is part of the parser, etc.  You can't change it without changing the language at it's core (e.g. you'd even have to change the abstract grammer upon which Python is built to support something like this).